# cakephp1.2 set ajax url to be used by multiple routes

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, routes

Hi I am modifying a very old website built using cakephp1.2.
Here is part of my view structure:
[my view structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0pcd.png)

the website was originally built to allow the user to access the content of the **add.cpt** by using either **"/"** or **"accounts/add"** 
which is accomplished by following code:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'accounts', 'action' => 'add'));
```

The problem I encounter is that I added a ajax request in **add.ctp** that requests some data from the controller. So I have something like this:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'someajaxrequest',
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: {}
 }).done(function(data){
 });
```

Then a function called someajaxrequest in **accounts_controller.php**

However, the request only works when being access through the route **"accounts/add"** and does now work when being accessed through **"/"** because it cannot find the function in the controller through this route.

I cannot abandon the **"/"** page because there are people using that page. 
I tired to redirect **"/"** to **"accounts/add"** but cakephp 1.2 does not support **router::redirect**. 
Is there a way I can fix this issue?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL in your AJAX call need to be absolute.

If it is relative it will work in one case but *not* the other.

So make sure that this

`url: 'someajaxrequest',`

users and **absolute** url and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks!! I changed it to url: '/useraccounts/accounts/someajaxrequest' and it fixed the issue.

Comment: well, if that fixed your issue please accept my answer as the solution